# Android Studio Not Showing My Real Device To Debug App

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-emulator, usb-debugging

When i am trying to connect my real device (Huawei Y6 Pro) to run app on my device its showing nothing. But on the other hand when i am connecting my another device(Samsung Galaxy S3), It showing perfectly and and i can run my app on this device. But why my Huawei device is not showing up on emulator/rubable list.

**Some Relevant Information**

- I enabled USB Debugging option under Developer Option.
- Connected USB as Camera (PTP).

Some screenshot about my device and its drivers

[Device USB Driver Condition in Device Mannager (in Windows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga2lJ.png)

[Android Studio Runable Device List (No USB Device Found)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25VBy.png)

What can i do now to fix it??

Comment: Try to download / update your mobile device USB driver

Comment: @SriHari when i am trying to update my driver its saying that "Device is up to dated". What next??

Comment: Install [Huawei Device Manager](http://consumer.huawei.com/minisite/HiSuite_en/index.html). This will install the missing device driver (USB driver). Connect your device _USB as MTP_. If that not worked connect your phone to the system and restart the mobile phone with USB debugging enabled. This will install device driver if not installed correctly. And sometimes it might be the problem of USB cable.

Comment: @Shashanth You Saved My Life. Finally It Worked.!!!! Thanks Bro

Comment: Glad it worked. :) Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you still have't figured it out or for anyone else who has the same problem here is how I resolved mine.

Go to this [link](http://adbdriver.com/documentation/how-to-install-adb-driver-on-windows-8-10-x64.html) and install ADB Driver on your Windows.